# Why am I getting OutOfMemoryException ? (see simple code below)

Tags: android, exception, imageview, android-memory

In my example application I have one ImageView in the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bigimage" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The dimension of the image is (width*height): 2288*1712
The bitmap configuration is the default: ARGB_8888 , so the size of the image loaded in the memory is: 2288 * 1712 * 4byte = 15 668 224 byte
The memory limit of the heap on my device is 128 MB ( what I know by Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()  ).

If I run the program I get OutofMemoryException. But why? Let's see the log below. The 15668240-byte is OK, that is what I calculated above. No problem so far. However what is the 141014032-byte allocation below?? Where does it come from?

```
08-26 18:21:35.133: I/dalvikvm-heap(31986): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.295MB for 15668240-byte allocation
08-26 18:21:35.204: I/dalvikvm-heap(31986): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 141014032-byte allocation
08-26 18:21:35.224: E/dalvikvm-heap(31986): Out of memory on a 141014032-byte allocation.
```

The main Activity (the only Activity) is:

```
package com.example.homokozo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Comment: your bitmap is too large and your app is exceeding memory allocated in heap leading to outofmemoryexception. You need to scale down your image

Comment: I'm interested in where the 141014032-byte allocation comes from?

Comment: what size is your bitmap image? Its bcoz of your image occupying more space

Comment: The image is png, and 232kb on the disk. 
The dimensions of the image are (width*height): 2288*1712 The bitmap configuration is the default: ARGB_8888 , so the size of the image loaded in the memory is: 2288 * 1712 * 4byte = 15 668 224 byte

Comment: you need to scale down http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html